# How can I display the image name on mouseover?

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 arrays, an image array and a price array. 
I have the images displaying, but I'd like to display the price, which at the moment I have held in the image name, when I mouseover the image, is it possible?

HTML

```html
        <section id=main>
          <!--populate with images from array-->
          <p id="photos" class="product_display">
          <script>getImage();</script>
        </section>
```

JS

```js
//image array for products
var imageArray = new Array();
imageArray[0]="images/coffee_prod_1.png";
imageArray[1]="images/coffee_prod_2.png";
imageArray[2]="images/coffee_prod_3.png";
imageArray[3]="images/coffee_prod_4.png";
imageArray[4]="images/coffee_prod_5.png";
imageArray[5]="images/coffee_prod_6.png";
imageArray[6]="images/coffee_prod_7.png";

//price array for products
var priceArray = ["€11.90", "€12.90", "€13.90", "€14.90", "€15.90", "€16.90", "€17.90"];

function getImage(){
                    
                    var container = document.getElementById("photos");

                    for (var i=0; i < imageArray.length; ++i) {
                    var img = new Image();
                    img.src = imageArray[i];
                    img.className = "product_details";
                    img.name = priceArray[i];
                    container.appendChild(img);                    
                    }

}
```

I thought I might be able to add something like 'img.onmouseover = imageMouseOver(priceArray[i]);' to my getImage function, and then have something inside the function that would display the image name (ideally over the image) on mouseover. I was hoping to apply an opaque colour too so the image name might be clearer.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried the img.title property ?

Comment: Would setting the image title do the trick ? img.title = priceArray[i] or do u want something more fancy ?

Comment: yeah, are you against storing the price in the image name? You should leave that, then just use regex (or something) to parse that price out.

Comment: `title` seems perfect for this job !

Comment: img.title works for the moment! I was looking for something a little fancier but I'm happy with that for now, I can trick around with the example below and see if I can figure something else out but title works perfectly in the meantime. Thanks for the answers, much appreciated (can't upvote at the moment I'm afraid, don't have enough points)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest creating a container div for each photo, and in each container add your  and like another div that contains the price. Set the price divs hidden at first with display:none or something, and then in your javascript add some listeners to show and hide it:

```
for (var i=0; i < imageArray.length; ++i) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = imageArray[i];
    img.className = "product_details";
    var container = document.createElement("div");
    var price = document.createElement("div");
    price.innerHTML = priceArray[i];
    //Style your price and image elements so they fit in the container and the price is displayed over the image etc
    container.appendChild(price);
    container.appendChild(img);

    container.onmouseover = function() {
        container.getElementByClass("price").style.display = "block";
    };
    container.onmouseout = function() {
        container.getElementByClass("price").style.display = "none";
    };                 
}
```

You may need to fiddle with the onmouseover/out events a bit if showing the price div messes it up i.e. onmouseover is called on the layer with the highest z index instead of container, I haven't tried it but this should give you a rough idea

Answer (score 0):

Working example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/0vts5291/

HTML

```
<section id=main>
    <!--populate with images from array-->
    <p id="photos" class="product_display">
</section>
```

JS

```
var imageArray = new Array();
imageArray[0]="images/coffee_prod_1.png";
imageArray[1]="images/coffee_prod_2.png";
imageArray[2]="images/coffee_prod_3.png";
imageArray[3]="images/coffee_prod_4.png";
imageArray[4]="images/coffee_prod_5.png";
imageArray[5]="images/coffee_prod_6.png";
imageArray[6]="images/coffee_prod_7.png";

//price array for products
var priceArray = ["€11.90", "€12.90", "€13.90", "€14.90", "€15.90", "€16.90", "€17.90"];

function getImage() {
    var container = document.getElementById("photos");

    for (var i = 0; i < imageArray.length; ++i) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = imageArray[i];
        img.className = "product_details";
        img.name = priceArray[i];
        img.title = priceArray[i];
        container.appendChild(img);
    }
}

getImage();
```